# Failed to parse URL from cadence-parser.wasm

Tags: node.js, webassembly, npm-package, onflow-cadence

I am trying to utilize [Cadence Parser package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@onflow/cadence-parser) in one of my project and for some reason I am getting the error from title.

I've used example provided in README:

```js
import { CadenceParser } from "@onflow/cadence-parser";

(async () => {
    const parser = await CadenceParser.create("cadence-parser.wasm");

    const ast = parser.parse(`
        pub contract HelloWorld {
            pub fun hello() {
                log("Hello, world!")
            }
        }
`);
})();
```

And getting the following error

```bash
TypeError: Failed to parse URL from cadence-parser.wasm
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11600:11) {
  [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
```

I've tried to copy `wasm` file from package folder into root - thinking that maybe paths are messed up somehow, but that didn't work either.

Node.js v20.7.0

### Working Solution

The only solution that was working for me is following:

```
import { CadenceParser } from "@onflow/cadence-parser";
import * as fs from "fs"

(async () => {
    let file = fs.readFileSync('./cadence-parser.wasm');
    const parser = await CadenceParser.create(file);

    const ast = parser.parse(`
        pub contract HelloWorld {
            pub fun hello() {
                log("Hello, world!")
            }
        }
`);

    console.log({ast})
})();
```

Otherwise I was getting errors about incorret URL, wrong type passed to  `WebAssembly.instantiate` and inability to fullfil fetch.

Answer (score 0):

The package is designed for use in browsers at the moment, usage in server runtimes like Node.JS is not supported yet. This is because the package uses the `fetch` function, which [does not support `file:` URLs in Node.JS](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/48554). Please open a feature request issue, PRs are also very welcome!